# Android - Contact list (Duplicated numbers)

Tags: java, android

My code shows a contact list. This is my fragment in a tabbed activity:

```
public class Tab2Contact extends Fragment {

    ListView listViewContacts;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS=100;
    ArrayList contacts;
    Cursor c;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_contact, container, false);

        listViewContacts=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewContacts);
        int permissionCheck= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        if (permissionCheck== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            showContacts();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contacts);
        listViewContacts.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }


    private void showContacts(){

        c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC ");
        contacts=new ArrayList();
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            String contactName=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phNumber=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            contacts.add(contactName+"\n"+phNumber);

        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I remove duplicated numbers from it?
2. How can I separate name and number into two separate arrays?

Comment: I was able to separate it into two arrays only needs solution for duplication

Comment: Please edit your question to show your enhancements and then clarify the single question.

Comment: use HashSet instead of ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a Set or Map and put phNumber as key. When you iterate over to get contacts:

```
HashMap<String, String> phNumberMap = new HashMap<>();
while (c.moveToNext()){
    phNumberMap.put(phNumber, contactName);
}
```

Then iterate over HashMap again to create two separate arrays from HashMap.